# Text processing command: If 'x' but not 'y' then add 'z' at the end of line

Tags: bash, awk, sed

Let's say I have the following input:

```
CH12
CH23au
RCH34
CH99de
ZE33a
CH88aude
CHa
```

And I want the output to be this:

```
CH12au
CH23au
RCH34
CH99deau
ZE33a
CH88aude
CHaau
```

Based on the rule that the line must start with 'CH' and does not have the pattern 'au'.

How would I accomplish this?

I assume I would have to use sed? or maybe awk?

Comment: The exact command that solved my case before I learned about patches: export PATH=${PATH}:/var/lib/npm/.npm-global/bin && \
grep -q "^PATH" /etc/security/pam_env.conf && \
sudo sed -i.bak 's@^PATH.*@PATH           DEFAULT='"${PATH}"'@g' /etc/security/pam_env.conf || \
sudo sed -i.bak '$ a\PATH           DEFAULT='"${PATH}"'' /etc/security/pam_env.conf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^CH/{/au/!s/$/au/}' file
```

Focus on lines beginning `CH` and if they don't contain `au` append it.

Comment: I should have mentioned this was actually about a variable, but thanks to you I managed to solve it with: sed -i.bak '/^CH/{\|'"$foo"'|! {s|$|'"$foo"'|}}' file

Answer (score 3):

Here is a simple Awk script which looks for CH at the beginning of a line without au. The final `1` is a common idiom for "print all input lines" and `$0` is the current input line.

```
awk '/^CH/ && ! /au/ { $0 = $0 "au" }1' file
```

If you want the suffix in an external variable, that requires a minor refactoring.

```
awk -v suf="au" '/^CH/ && $0 !~ suf { $0 = $0 suf } 1' file
```

Answer (score 1):

With sed :

```
sed '/au/!s/^CH\(.*\)/CH\1au/' file
```

- `/au/!`: in lines not containing `au`
- `s` : substitute
- `^CH` line starting with `CH`
- `\(.*\)` followed by any character (captured with `\(` `\)`
- `CH\1au` replace matching pattern with `CH` followed by captured character followed by ending `au`

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
awk '
{
    if(substr($0, 0, 2) == "CH")
    {
        if(index($0, "au") == 0)
            printf("%sau\n",$0)
        else
            print $0
    }
    else
        print $0
}' file
```

Comment: @Ren I recommend you read the book Effective Awk Programming, 4th Edition, by Arnold Robbins as you seem to be missing the point of awk.

Comment: @EdMorton - Thanks for your suggestion, I will read the book Effective Awk Programming.